# sockets - client/server - sending string after binary file transfer

Tags: python, sockets, binaryfiles

I'm working on a Python client/server script. One of the issues I'm hitting is trying to tell the server I'm done sending the file. Here is a step by step of my logic:

- Client connects to server & sends the file name.
- Server tells the client to send the file.
- Client sends file and server saves it under the passed name.
- Client sends a string ('EOF') to tell the server it is done sending the file.
- Server sends a string ('TRXOK') to the client that the transfer is ok.
- Server does some stuff and send additional data to client.
- Server closes file/connection
- Client closes connection and does things based on the last data received.

The problem I'm having is telling the server that the file transfer is done. I send 'EOF' but the server doesn't understand it. When I send the file name I send it as:

```
ClientSS.sendall(FileName.encode())
```

and the server receives it:

```
FileName  = ClientSS.recv(1024).decode()
```

This works and is the same method I use for sending the EOF string.
The file is in binary so I just do a:

```
Data = File.read(1024)
HostSS.sendall(Data)
```

and on the server end:

```
RawData = ClientSS.recv(1024)
```

This too works well. However the following code doesn't (doesn't find the EOF):

```
while True:                          #receive file
    try:
        RawData = ClientSS.recv(1024)
    except socket.error:
        TimerCount += 1              #increment timer count
        if TimerCount >= 5 :         #waited 1/2 sec, no activity so error out
            Ret = 'ERR_FILE_RECV'
            break
        continue
    EOFData = ''
    try:
        EOFData = RawData.decode().strip()
    except:
        pass
    if EOFData == 'EOF':           #Rec'd a EOF so we're done with file
        break
    WriteFile.write(RawData)        #write raw data to file
```

When I run this code the file is transferred and saved (along with the EOF string).  The EOF conditional never finds the "EOF".  Any ideas on why the above snippet isn't catching the EOF?

The code I use to send the file & EOF:

```
while True:                  #send the file
        Data = File.read(1024)
        if not Data:             #hit EOF, no more data
            break                #Exit file send loop
        HostSS.sendall(Data)
SendEOF = 'EOF'
HostSS.sendall(SendEOF.encode())
```

Comment: You answered the question yourself. "EOF" gets appended to the file data. You have to look for EOF substring, not for exact match. Anyway, the protocol is broken, because "EOF" may appear in the file itself.

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of socket info transfer is wrong.  My thinking was that the client sends 1024 long parts of the file until there's nothing more to send.  The server receives each of those 1024 parts.  Once the client has nothing more to send of the file it then does a new send that is just the EOF string.  You're saying that the socket internals is appending the EOF to the last file send even though I'm doing it in a new send?

Comment: I added the code I use to send the file & then the EOF to the orig post.

Comment: The socket won't keep the granularity you wrote it with. It could break it up into pieces, or it could bunch pieces together. You don't have any control over that.

Comment: @TugboatBill TCP is a continuos stream of bytes. Send the file size first (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring), then data.

Comment: I have it working.  I am using a second connection for the file and I'm using the file size to determine when it has been fully received.

Comment: Your solution sounds a lot like FTP.